# Strange Box-shadow bug on Chrome 51 while scrolling

Tags: html, css, google-chrome, box-shadow

So while making a website I discovered a strange `box-shadow` bug on Chrome 51, my website has a fixed header with a `box-shadow`, and when I scroll up or down the box-shadow leaves some marks (horizontal gray lines) :

[image: bug]

Also I can't reproduce this bug on a jsfiddle ([link of the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/coaL2hvL/3/)) and on other browsers like Firefox or Internet Explorer.

Is it a bug? What could be the problem?

**UPDATE 1**

It seems to work on Chrome 49

Comment: can you show the real link? so I can test. thanks

Comment: @Raduken I work on local.

Comment: well like that it's hard to help you :(,  can you use: https://ngrok.com/ so like that i will be able to see your localhost, its very security

Comment: Same on my project, we just remove the box-shadow to fix it...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I encountered this bug.
I don't know what causes this but here's a simple way to fix it:

Add 0.1px to the shadow's blur

```
box-shadow: 0 2px 0.1px #yourcolor;
```

The lines should disappear that way and the blur isn't really visible.