# Chrome bug display lines with box shadow

Tags: css, google-chrome, webkit, chromium

I noticed the following bug in Google Chrome while developing a website. The logos and text has been changed for obvious reasons.

**Normal Display :**

[image: Normal display]

**After the bug appears display:** (notice the gray lines under the navbar)

[image: Buggy display]

Context :

- At first load, the pages are **always** normal. The bug appears only when I scroll down then up multiple times. It is not always the same lines, and keep changing positions when I keep scrollin up/down. But always the same size of lines and same color.
- When I removed the box-shadow of the navbar, the lines do not appear anymore.
- The bug only appear in Google Chrome, not in Firefox nor Edge (can't try in Safari).
- I got a nvidia GPU on Windows 10.
- It is definitely due to the box shadow because I can reproduce the bug in other websites by adding this line of CSS (example in SO website below).

[image: SO bug]

**Lines of code involved :**

```
box-shadow: 0 1px 0 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.1)
```

Note : It still appears with 1 in opacity instead of 0.1.

The closest I found was this issue : [Strange diagonal lines in Chrome/Chromium (bug?)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41946156/strange-diagonal-lines-in-chrome-chromium-bug)

But I am not sure it is the same thing since it is not the same appearance, the same pattern, and does not appear for the same reasons.

Does anyone faced the same thoughts and can affirm it is the same issue / found a fix of this bug or is it relevant to report it to Chrome ?

Comment: May be a graphics driver problem. Have you tried switching off Chrome's hardware acceleration? Or maybe the driver can be updated.

Comment: Hello, I had the same issue, have you tried this solution? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612255/strange-box-shadow-bug-on-chrome-51-while-scrolling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had a similar issue in Chrome, where changes in the box-shadow on an input with :focus state would 90% of the time show a line underneath it: [input bug with box-shadow](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AcRsr.png)

What fixed it for me was adding `position:relative` to the element with the `box-shadow` property.

Comment: I've been trying to find a way around this bug for a while, your solution worked perfectly - thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Using `position: relative` did not work for me. This solution did work for this bug however: [Strange Box-shadow bug on Chrome 51 while scrolling](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37612255/strange-box-shadow-bug-on-chrome-51-while-scrolling).

> Add 0.1px to the shadow's blur

`box-shadow: Xpx Ypx 0.1px Spx #yourcolor;`